# Javascript: communications between frames

Tags: javascript, security, frames

I have two different applications loaded into different frames.
I need them to communicate
I know that javascript security model does not allow frames loaded from different domains to communicate
but since I control both applications maybe there is a way to allow frames loaded from specific another domain to communicate with this frame

If it is not possible what's the hack around?
Apps are different and I need to load them at different domains (or at least different ports)
I can not run them as one app

Comment: Try http://easyxdm.net/wp/ I don't know what it has under the hood, but I guess it is more than a simple postMessage... There is another jquery plugin for cross domain messaging, but I forgot its name.

Answer (score 1):

If they share top-level domain (e.g. `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`), then you can set `document.domain = 'example.com';` to [relax same-origin restriction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.domain).

If you support only HTML5 browsers, then there's [postMessage()](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/comms.html#web-messaging) exactly for cross-domain communication.

Other options are [JSONP](http://remysharp.com/2007/10/08/what-is-jsonp/) (fancy name for a cross-domain `<script>` tag) and proxying of `XmlHttpRequest` via the server on each domain.

Comment: postMessage is the best solution for me